# Remove/clear rectangles drawn by Graphics#fillRect()

Tags: java, swing

I've made this to draw bar graphs, but when I do repaint() the new chart is drawn on top of the previous one. After a few repaints with new arrays it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLDSh.png). **How can I clear or remove drawn bars?**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BarChart extends JPanel {

    private int[] array;

    public BarChart(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public void setArray(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //Determine longest bar
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Integer value : array) {
            max = Math.max(max, value);
        }
        //Paint bars
        int width = (getWidth() / array.length) - 2;
        int x = 1;
        for (Integer value : array) {
            int height = (int) ((getHeight() - 5) * ((double) value / max));
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(x, getHeight() - height, width, height);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(x, getHeight() - height, width, height);
            x += (width + 2);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can call

```
g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );
```

first thing in your `paintComponent()` method.

Answer (score 3):

If the panel is opaque (they usually are by default), then you can do this to fill the component with the background colour:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Your code here
}
```